# Running a batch file at logon to a server

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've made this batch file to open my startup applications when I log in to my work server remotely as a user. The IT has deactivated the use of startup applications. So all users must log in an then open one application at a time. And I find it a real waste of time doing that.

I've therefore, read up around on how to create this batch file (since I'm no programmer) but I receive the error of "unc paths are not supported. defaulting to windows directory" when I run this batch file. However, during the time I'm logged on to the remote server, if I have run all these applications once at least, then the batch file actually fires up and is able to open all these applications.

Here's the batch file code:

```
@echo off

"D:\Program\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE"
"\\192.168.xx.xx\home$\user\Documents\Shortcuts\iexplore.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
"\\192.168.xx.xx\home$\user\Documents\Works-2015\Personal\Time Tracker-General Tasks.xlsm"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\4D\4D v14 R4\4D\4D.exe" "\\server details\application details\applicationclient.4dlink"

Exit
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to 'net use' the unc share to a drive letter ? I assume Windows does not know you are allowed to read from the share yet.

Comment: Is the batch on the remote server. If so don't worry about it. See here for more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Setting_a_UNC_working_directory_from_a_shortcut